# Substitutions unions vs composition are not the same?

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm studying substitutions. A substitution is a set of mappings from variables to terms $\{a \rightarrow b; c \rightarrow d;...\}$.

Given these substitutions:

- $\sigma_1 := \{x \rightarrow y\}$
- $\sigma_2 := \{y \rightarrow x\}$
- $\sigma_3 := \sigma_1 \cup \sigma_2 $

And this term : $t := f(x, y)$ are following substitutions correct?

- $t\sigma_1 \Rightarrow f(y, y)$
- $t\sigma_2 \Rightarrow f(x, x)$
- $t\sigma_1\sigma_2 \Rightarrow f(x, x)$
- $t\sigma_3 \Rightarrow f(y, x)$

For some reason, I expected that $t\sigma_1\sigma_2 = t\sigma_3$ which seems not to be the case, I came across this during the implementation of substitutions here https://gist.github.com/dhilst/81592505f2bdc886e9085bd24d352e60 where I implemented the substitution by implementing a function that does one substitution and then composing multiple substitutions from a list, and then implementing the notation $t\{a \rightarrow b; c \rightarrow d; ...\}$ as $t\{a \rightarrow b\}\{c \rightarrow d\}\{...\}$ which looks wrong now

Comment: I was revisiting this topic and managed to implement substitution correctly here, https://gist.github.com/dhilst/c69cdd5c3c144bd48c68f81422abac48

What I do is use a wrapping value to bookkeep the replacements so that I don't double replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, a substitution in first-order logic consists in simultanously replacing variables for their mapped terms, whereas the composition is the result of applying the substitutions in the order they are given (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_(logic)#First-order_logic).

Hence, when applying a composition of substitutions, one substitution may affect the other one according to the order they have (like in your examples, first applying $\{x\rightarrow y\}$ and then applying $\{y\rightarrow x\}$ is the same as applying $\{x\rightarrow x; y \rightarrow x\}$; but first applying $\{y\rightarrow x\}$ and then $\{x \rightarrow y\}$ would result into $\{y \rightarrow y; x\rightarrow y\}$). This is not the case with a union of substitutions (where $\{x \rightarrow y\} \cup \{y \rightarrow x\}$ is the same as $\{y \rightarrow x\} \cup \{x \rightarrow y\}$).

Comment: So in the third case, to1o2, I would get f(x,y) not f(x,x)

Comment: I think the associativity is broken in my implementation because (to1)o2 <> t(o1o2) :/

Comment: I'd say that first applying $\{x\rightarrow y\}$ and then applying $\{y\rightarrow x\}$ is the same as applying $\{x\rightarrow x; y\rightarrow x\} \cong \{y\rightarrow x\}$ (and not $\{x\rightarrow x\}$).

Comment: You are right @chi, I've edited the answer accordingly. Many thanks ;)